# How to preserve view memory when dismissing dialog?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-view

In my android app activity, I create a global variable for a LinearLayout. Then I create a dialog box and add the LinearLayout to this dialog box. Then when I dismiss the dialog box, I believe what happens is that the LinearLayout variable gets deleted, as in its value becomes null or something.

What I want is that the LinearLayout data not get deleted when the dialog box gets dismissed. This is because if I want to open the dialog box window again, I would be adding the LinearLayout view again, and I do this so that it would remember the states of the views inside that LinearLayout, such as radio groups and checkboxes.

Is this possible to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you safe the reference to the LinearLayout in some variable and don't set it to null yourself, it won't be null after dismissing the dialog.

However, I think you can not attach a View to a parent twice.

The best way to persist state is:

1. As config changes and other things will pause your app, store the state some where else, persist it across activity restarts with `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onCreate()`. There is a `Bundle` passed to both methods, where you can save your state.
2. Restore your state when creating the new layout.
3. Optional: Save a reference to the dialog.

Comment: Is there a way to override the onbackpressed event for Dialogs?

Comment: You don't need to. Just add on{*something*}Listener to the views inside the layout and save the state, when it get's changed. not on dismiss.